# iPhone: How to control two tables within one NIB

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I need two UITableViews in the same NIB.  I have used IB and created a view with the two tables.

My header file contains the ViewController and two classes, one for each of the tables (see below).  In IB I can connect each table's delegate and datasource to FileOwner, but I cannot work out how to create the IBOutlet connection. I'm getting this message:  ***-[News tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d3c0
2011-12-11 07:20:27.480 myCity1[659:707] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[News tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d3c0'***

Here's the header file:

```
@interface News : UIViewController {

}

@end

@interface TownNews : UITableViewController {

UITableView *townNewsTable;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *townNewsTable;

@end

@interface GeneralNews : UITableViewController {

UITableView *generalNewsTable;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *generalNewsTable;

@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was dealing with this thing in one of my projects (you can watch it: free app with name IJCAI11 in the appstore; the tab 'People' (there the indexing is done with a separate tableView)); and as far as I see by the code above, you're making things to be too complicated. I'll describe how I did it instead of saying what you shouldn't do :)

I had only one class, let's say YaddaYaddaViewController.

```
@interface YaddaYaddaViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    UITableView *tableView1;
    UITableView *tableView2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView * tableView1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView * tableView2;

@end
```

Note that the viewController is derived from UIViewController, not UITableViewController (the goal of class UITableViewController is to be able to implement simple tableView in 2 minutes, for more custom stuff you should always use UIViewController. To read more about that, take a glance at the documentation of UITableViewController class).

In the IB for "File's Owner" I simply set YaddaYaddaViewController;
I link the tableView1 and tableView2 outlets to the proper tables in the View;
I link the delegate and the datasource to the both tableView1/2, so I have 'multiple' delegate and datasource.

And finally, in the code, for all delegate methods (e.g. tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)
I just pay attention to the tableView value, a delegate-event of which caused the calling of this method, like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
        // some code here
    } else {
        // alternative code here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Makaron.  That looks much easier.  Appreciated

Answer (score -1):

@makaron whatEver he said is absolutely correctly except

1)  if you are declaration of UItableView and want to create tableview with Library(not programmatically) then change your header file to :-

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView2;
}

@end
```

and in all the tableview delegates like

NumberOfRowsInSection,NumberOfSection,CellForRowAtIndexPath,DidSelectRowAtIndexPath Check the conditions

```
if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
        // code for tableView1
    } else {
        // code for tableView2
    }
```

Also if you don't want to declare two tableViews in the header file.Drop Down two tableview's from library to View and set tag to each of them and compare with the help of tag in all the tableview delegates like

NumberOfRowsInSection,NumberOfSection,CellForRowAtIndexPath,DidSelectRowAtIndexPath Check the conditions

```
//I am assuming that tableView1 has tag set to be 1

    if (tableView.tag==1) {
            // code for tableView1
        } else {
            // code for tableView2
        }
```

Comment: I don't see, to be honest, how the first part of your answer is different from mine. About the second one ... yes, also an approach, but I prefer to stay in the range of objects (OOP approach if you prefer) instead of tags where it's possible. Just note that I didn't say smth was wrong with Jeremy's code, except I suspected him in overcomplicating things :)

Comment: first of all when you are making through Interface builder (In other words if you are not making tableView programmatically)then you have to give IBOutlet in the header file. IBOutlet means Interface Builder Outlet. and second thing when you have to deal with only one view you don't have set the property of UITableView's to be non atomic and retain.

Comment: emmm... thanks for some info which I got from the very first HelloWorld apple's manual )) Man, I've set IBOutlet, and it's set according to apple doc; dude, I've set nonatomic and retain: at the same string, also according to apple doc.

Comment: This is more of a comment on the makaron's answer than an actual answer.